# Delete MySQLcolumn

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I need delete column from

```
SELECT * FROM 36496839_woodensky.skladovekarty00002;

ALTER TABLE skladovekarty00002 
DROP COLUMN Description
```

> Error Code: 1091. Can't DROP 'Description'; check that column/key exists

DB: MySql 5.1
Workbench
Some issue ?

Comment: Can you add the create table Statement please?

Comment: You included the database name `36496839_woodensky` in the `SELECT` statement. Is it as simple as you not having selected the database with `USE 36496839_woodensky` before the `ALTER`?

Comment: (in other words, does `SELECT * FROM skladovekarty00002` also fail?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your current database is not 36496839_woodensky, you will need to include the databasename in your alter table statement. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE 36496839_woodensky.skladovekarty00002 DROP COLUMN Description
```